# How to identify value of variable $A$ at which variable $B$ exhibits discontinuity

Tags: least-squares, linear-model, binary-data, probit, threshold

I have reason to believe that an indicator variable $B$ is generated by an underlying process that disproportionately assigns a value of 1 to $B$ once another variable $A$ has passed a certain threshold point. I do not know what this threshold is. I only observe the value of $A$ and $B$ over time for multiple individuals in a panel setting. I need to exploit the relationship between the two variables to identify the value of $A$ that is most likely to be the threshold point. What is the best way to search for this threshold?

Answer (score 0):

One potential approach is to estimate the indicator $B$ as a function of indicators for all levels of $A$ except one. One could then find the parameter with the largest estimate and assume the threshold lies at the value of $A$ that corresponds with the largest parameter. This can be represented using a linear probability model as follows (assume $A$ can take $n$ different values):

$$B_{i,t}=\beta_0+\beta_11(A \geq 1)+...+\beta_n1(A \geq n)+\alpha X+\varepsilon_i,$$

where $1(A \geq a)$ is an indicator that takes the value of 1 for all observations with $A \geq a$.

The above equation would be estimated via OLS, and we would simply look for the indicator with the largest significant $\beta$.

This seems like the most straightforward way to identify this threshold. However, I would love to learn about alternative approaches because the above regression is giving me results that don't make sense. The biggest problem is that the relationship between $B$ and $A$ should be monotonic and positive, however, the parameters on the indicators are currently switching between positive and negative. I would appreciate suggestions on how to model this phenomenon. Links to sources would be much appreciated.